# Trying to install giveaway-grabber, getting error that says the operation was rejected by the operating system

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, npm

I'm trying to install a script that allows me to run through all the amazon giveaways. I downloaded node.js and permission is denied every time I try to install giveaway-grabber.

I've tried using sudo but that doesn't work either. I'm running on MacOS.

npm install -g giveaway-grabber

or

sudo npm install -g giveaway-grabber

"The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended)."

I'm really new to scripts and coding in general so I'd appreciate the simplest explanations.

Answer (score 0):

On the git repo page another user had a similar issue ([git repo)](https://github.com/jpchip/giveaway-grabber/issues/122)

They resolved with:
    sudo npm install -g giveaway-grabber --unsafe-perm

Answer (score 0):

I was irritated by the same problem while installing Mina protocol's CLI but I figured it out somehow and it was easier than you think.

```
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/reetbatra/.npm"
npm cache clean --force
sudo npm install -g zkapp-cli
```

finally i was able to install zkapp by just clearing the cache.